# $_FILES empty, enctype is set, I've used it before

Tags: php, file, upload, isnullorempty

FILES is empty, but it shouldn't be.  I've uploaded files before.  The file is small enough, and I'm using enctype (for many other people that's the problem).  I'm uploading txt files.  I've also used this same exact setup in another php file to upload bigger txt files, to the same directory, and it works (I actually just copied the code from that other file!).

Here's my forms (top one submits bottom one):

```
<form name=fileForm action='FTtoXML.php' enctype="multipart/form-data" method='post'>
<input type='file' name='file' id='file' onChange=document.forms['saveForm'].submit()>
</form>

<form name=saveForm id=saveForm action='FTtoXML.php' enctype="multipart/form-data" method=post>
<input type=hidden id=gameToSave name=gameToSave value='yes'>
</form>
```

Then some debugging php code:

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
echo "no file error<p>";
echo "var_dump: ".var_dump($_FILES)."<br>";
echo 'file_uploads: '. ini_get('file_uploads'). '<br />';
echo 'upload_tmp_dir: '. ini_get('upload_tmp_dir'). '<br />';
echo 'upload_max_filesize: '. ini_get('upload_max_filesize'). '<br />';
echo 'max_file_uploads: '. ini_get('max_file_uploads'). '<br />';
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
```

output:

```
var_dump: array(0) { }  
file_uploads: 1
upload_tmp_dir: /tmp
upload_max_filesize: 10M
max_file_uploads: 
Upload: 
Type: 
Size: 0 kB
Temp file:
```

So you can see there's no name, type, etc.  Then when I try to open the file,

```
if (file_exists("uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
{
echo "filealreadyexists<br>";
}
```

it's true, output: 
filealreadyexists

So it seems like a null filename is seen as existing if it's not there?  Therefore later when I try to move the file...

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],  "uploads/mydoc.txt");
```

...it doesn't work, and when I try to fopen the file...

```
$file = fopen("uploads/mydoc.txt", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
```

...it says "Unable to open file!" because the file doesn't exist in the directory.

Comment: in your onchange, onChange=document.forms['saveForm'].submit(), you probably are submitting wrong form. i think it shoud be, onChange=document.forms['fileForm'].submit()

Comment: You submit the wrong form, why not make it all one form so you don't have to worry about the issue of submitting the wrong one?

Answer (score 2):

Change the HTML you show to this:

```
<form name='saveForm' action='FTtoXML.php' enctype="multipart/form-data" method='post'>
<input type='file' name='file' id='file' onChange=document.forms['saveForm'].submit()>
<input type=hidden id=gameToSave name=gameToSave value='yes'>
</form>
```

That way it's all in one form.  You were submitting the bottom form which didn't include the `<input type='file'`